# Writing to two or more data extensions at once

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, preference-center

I'm quite a newby at this (green)

I'm creating custom subscription center. I have two data extensions which I need to insert/upsert data to.

1. Newsletter_Subscribers (EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName, Gender, DateOfBirth, OptIn, DateSubscribed, DateModified, DateUnsubscribed
2. Newsletter_Subscriber_Topics (NST_EmailAddress, NST_TopicID, NST_OptIn, NST_DateSubscribed, NST_DateUnsubscribed)

I've created a 4 connected cloud pages:
a) Form - collects data (Email, FirstName, LastName, Gender, DateOfBirth, TopicID)
b) Process - (insert) 
c) Settings
d) Process2 (upsert)

Everything works fine if I use only one DE, but in that case when customer unsubscribes it unsubscribes from all, so here is when the second DE comes in handy, but I just can figure out how to write some data in one and the rest in the second DE.

Is there an option to do it with ampscript or just with automation?

Tnx.

Comment: may I ask - why two DEs?

Why not have a boolean field for each newsletter where TRUE = subscribed and FALSE = unsubscribed?

Comment: We talked about a solution where we could track our subscribers habits as how long were they subscribed to a specific themed newsletter, what triggered them to unsub, and so on...

Comment: still seems like you can do this in a single DE with a field for "subscribe date" and "unsubscribe date" by newsletter... just a thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your scenario and understanding the question correctly.

You have two DEs
1. Newsletter_Subscribers - This DE stores subscriptions and all other data(kind of a master)
2. Newsletter_Subscriber_Topics - This DE stores topic wise subscription

I would suggest you to do take two actions

1. Since, you are capturing the information on cloud page and already using ampscript, you can use that information to upsert in the Newsletter_Subscribers DE and insert/update Newsletter_Subscriber_Topics.
   Assuming that the personal data (first name, email) is the most updated data that you would want to update in your master DE as well.
2. If your business use case permits, you can create a third DE which will just store your form submission data(with all the form fields as attributes- this is helpful in keeping a track of all the form submissions). You can then use this DE and automation in conjunction to update data in both the DEs mentioned above.

Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: It does. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Then don't forget to upvote the answer :P